# How to get details of all users using a particular application using PHP SDK?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I created an application in facebook. How to get details of all users of this application even

if they are not my facebook friends. I need a PHP SDK query

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use FQL with PHP sdk :

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Below is the query which should get you the desired results.

```
$config = array(
'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE is_app_user = '1'"));
```

For users table you can look at : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/

Though it is not tested but i can hope it will point you in right direction.

Comment: :I checked your answer. But i got an error->

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 604: Your statement is not indexable. The WHERE clause must contain an indexable column. Such columns are marked with * in the tables linked from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql thrown in /*****/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1106